# qq.FileUploader: Cancel submit

Tags: jquery, file-upload, ajax-upload

I'm using the plugin [qq.FileUploader](http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/).

Before submitting file, I want to know if a file with the same name has already been upload.

I'm using this code:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-requestDocuments'),
        action: '<%: Url.Action("Create", "RequestDocument") %>',
        params: { id: $('#RequestTempUploadFolderID').val() },
        sizeLimit: 10520000,
        onSubmit: function (id, fileName)
            $('#file-uploader-requestDocuments').find('.qq-upload-file').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == fileName) {
                    return false;
                return true;
            });
        }
    });
```

The return false is correct, but it does not stop the submit!

How stop the file upload, and there is a better way to get the file already uploaded?

Comment: May I upload upto 5GB file on network storage server using this article?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about doing that checking in your server side?! and returning a response in AJAX, for duplicate file names?!

**EDIT**

if your server response this:

```
{"success":"false", "errorMessage":"File name is duplicate!"}
```

you can have that JS code:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-requestDocuments'),
        action: '<%: Url.Action("Create", "RequestDocument") %>',
        params: { id: $('#RequestTempUploadFolderID').val() },
        sizeLimit: 10520000,
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            if(!responseJSON.success){alert(responseJSON.errorMessage);}
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes it's better. So now, why the function showMessage: function(message){ alert(message); } is never called?

Comment: actually now the showMessage will be not call! you should use onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){}, then u can grab the responseJSON and display a message.(will edit my answer to add that code)

Comment: May I upload upto 5GB file on network storage server using this article?